# Linux Mint Swap partition

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, linux-mint, swap

I've recently installed Linux Mint as a secondary OS to my laptop which already had Win 10 installed.

I could only add one partition for Linux Mint and  install Linux Mint without the swap partition as I got a message which was saying my HDD already had max number of partitions. Actually I was thinking I only had two partitions ,C and D , but apparently Windows had added an additional recovery partition so in total I had 4 partitions. Linux Mint seems to be working without any problems but I am now wondering, would it make any performance improvements if I had that swap partition? My laptop has 4 GB of ram.

If I want to reinstall Linux Mint with the swap , is there any way to do this with this setup?

[image: my hdd]

Comment: Some thoughts: 1) It isn't strictly necessary, but there are benefits to subdividing the Linux partition (typically into root, home, and swap).  If you just created it, redoing it wouldn't be a huge time waste at this point.  2) D: is a logical drive, so you could make the Linux partitions logical instead of primary without affecting the partition limit.  3) 26GB isn't a lot for the OS, swap, and your files.  You could look at shrinking at least D: to steal a little more space.  Use 4GB for swap.  Depending on how much software you expect to load, 15-20GB should be enough for root.  (cont'd)

Comment: Home depends on the extent of your own files.  Probably 10GB minimum.  More if you have big video, audio, or image collections or do editing of those, or plan to load a VM or Wine; so it would be better to have at least 10GB more than the 26 so you don't run out of space.